# Cannot Place Block in Unity, using UNET/Multiplayer

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, unityscript, unity-networking

I have been making a game for a long time and now I am setting up multiplayer. The problem is that any way I try to make an object be placed on every client will not work. Either an error is thrown or the object does not show up everywhere. My script is in JS. Here it is:

```
import UnityEngine.Networking;
public class minvantory extends NetworkBehaviour {
    var blockLayer : LayerMask = 1; 
    var range : float = Mathf.Infinity; 
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    var PIC : Texture;
    var invantory : Texture;
    var itemnumber : int = 1;
    var block1 : GameObject;
    var block2 : GameObject;
    var block3 : GameObject;
    var block4 : GameObject;
    var block5 : GameObject;
    var block6 : GameObject;
    var block7 : GameObject;
    var block8 : GameObject;
    var block9 : GameObject;
    var block10 : GameObject;
    var block11 : GameObject;
    var block12 : GameObject;
    var block13 : GameObject;
    var block14 : GameObject;
    var block15 : GameObject;
    var block16 : GameObject;
    var block17 : GameObject;
    var block18 : GameObject;
    var block19 : GameObject;
    @SyncVar
    var block : GameObject;
    var open : boolean;
    var escopen: boolean;
    var id : int = 0;
    var blocks : int = 0;
    var player : GameObject;
    var networked=false;
    var customSkin : GUISkin;
    var easter : GameObject;
    var missile: GameObject;
    //var x : playerlook;
    function Start(){
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
                return;
        blocks = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("blocks");
        //x = GameObject.Find("MainCamera").GetComponent(playerLook);
        Screen.lockCursor=true;
        Cursor.visible=true;
    }
    function Update() {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
                return;
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E)&&!escopen)
        {  
            if (open) 
                open = false;
            else 
                open = true;
            Screen.lockCursor=!open;
            Debug.Log("Open: " + open);
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape)&&!open)
        {  
            if (escopen) 
                escopen = false;
            else 
                escopen = true;
            Screen.lockCursor=!escopen;
            Debug.Log("Escopen: " + escopen);
        }
        if ((Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))||(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.X))&&!open&&!escopen&&!getCopn()){
            Debug.Log("BUILD");
            CmdBuild(block, id);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)&&!open&&!escopen&&!getCopn()) CmdErase();
    }

    function OnGUI (){  
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
                return;
        GUI.skin = customSkin;
        //GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(Screen.width-5,Screen.height-5,5,5), PIC, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit, true, 1);
        if(open){
            GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(0,50,350,500), invantory, ScaleMode.StretchToFill, true, 1);
            var tblock : GameObject=block;
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,80,120,20), "urainium")) {
                id = 1;
                tblock = block1;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,120,120,20), "nutrongun")) {
                tblock = block2;
                id = 2;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,160,120,20), "zaneite")) {
                tblock = block3;
                id = 3;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,200,120,20), "gravium")) {
                tblock = block4;
                id = 0;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,240,120,20), "asteroid")) {
                tblock = block5;
                id = 4;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,280,120,20), "gas")) {
                tblock = block6;
                id = 5;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,320,120,20), "steel")) {
                tblock = block7;
                id = 6;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,360,120,20), "rock")) {
                tblock = block8;
                id = 7;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,400,120,20), "dish")) {
                tblock = block9;
                id = 8;
            }
            if(GUI.Button(Rect(10,440,120,20), "rocket")){
                tblock = block11;
                id = 9;
            }
            if(GUI.Button(Rect(10,480,120,20), "crate")){
                tblock = block10;
                id = 10;
            }
            if(GUI.Button(Rect(140,80,120,20), "Y stabilizer")){
                tblock = block14;
                id = 13;
            }if(GUI.Button(Rect(140,120,120,20), "planet core")){
                tblock = block15;
                id = 14;
            }
            if(GUI.Button(Rect(140,160,120,20), "Control")){
                tblock = block16;
                id = 15;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (140,200,120,20), "lamp")) {
                tblock = block17;
                id = 16;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (140,240,120,20), "glass")) {
                tblock = block18;
                id = 17;
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (140,280,120,20), "plasma explosive")) {
                tblock = block19;
                id = 18;
            }
            if(GUI.Button(Rect(140,320,120,20), "computer")){
                tblock = block12;
                id = 11;
            }
            if(GUI.Button(Rect(140,360,120,20), "stabilizer")){
                tblock = block13;
                id = 12;
            }
            if(GUI.Button(Rect(140,400,120,20), "Easterment")){
                tblock = easter;
                id = 10000;
            }if(GUI.Button(Rect(140,440,120,20), "ICBM Launcher")){
                tblock = missile;
                id = 2030;
            }
            CmdSyncBlock(tblock);
            //}
        }
        else if(escopen){
            GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(0,50,350,500), invantory, ScaleMode.StretchToFill, true, 1);
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,60,280,40), "quit")) {
                saveWorld();
                Application.LoadLevel("GUI");
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,110,280,40), "reset and quit")) {
                PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("saved");
                Application.LoadLevel("GUI");
            }
            if (GUI.Button (Rect (10,160,280,40), "suicide")) {
                GetComponent.<mplayer>().health=0;
            }
        }else
            GUI.DrawTexture(Rect((Screen.width - PIC.width) / 2, (Screen.height - PIC.height) /2, PIC.width, PIC.height), PIC);
    }
    @Command
    function CmdSyncBlock(g: GameObject){
        block=g;
    }
    @Command
    function CmdBuild(obj : GameObject, x : int){
        var h: boolean=HitBlock();
        Debug.Log(h);
        if (h && hit.transform.tag != "Player"&&x!=2030) {
            //Debug.Log(hit.transform.tag); 
            var blockobj : GameObject;
            if(hit.transform.tag != "computer"&&hit.transform.tag!="thruster"){
                Debug.Log("Spawning...");
                blockobj = Instantiate(block, hit.transform.position+hit.normal, hit.transform.rotation);
                NetworkServer.Spawn(blockobj);
                blockobj.transform.rotation = hit.transform.rotation;
                if(blockobj.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>() && hit.rigidbody){
                    blockobj.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity=hit.rigidbody.velocity;
                    blockobj.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity=hit.rigidbody.angularVelocity;
                }
                blockobj.gameObject.AddComponent.<NetworkTransform>();
                blockobj.gameObject.GetComponent.<NetworkTransform>().enabled=true;
                Debug.Log("spawned.");
            }else if(hit.transform.tag == "thruster"){
                hit.transform.GetComponent("thrusterControl").Toggle();
            }else if(hit.transform.tag == "computer"){
                hit.transform.GetComponent("computer").Toggle();
                Debug.Log("I <3 computers!");
            }else{
                Debug.Log("BUILD ERROR");
            }

        }
        if(x==2030){
            blockobj = Instantiate(missile, transform.position+transform.forward, transform.rotation);
            NetworkServer.Spawn(blockobj);
            blockobj.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
            blockobj.GetComponent.<ICBM>().follow=h;
            if(blockobj.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>() && hit.rigidbody){
                blockobj.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity=hit.rigidbody.velocity;
                blockobj.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity=hit.rigidbody.angularVelocity;
            }
            blockobj.gameObject.AddComponent.<NetworkTransform>();
            blockobj.gameObject.GetComponent.<NetworkTransform>().enabled=true;
            Debug.Log(h);
            Debug.Log(hit);
            if(!h)
                return;
            blockobj.GetComponent.<ICBM>().target=hit.transform.gameObject;
            Debug.Log("FOLLOW!");
        }
    }
    @Command
    function CmdErase() { 
        if (HitBlock() && hit.transform.tag != "Player" && hit.transform.tag != "do not destroy"){
            if(networked)
                NetworkServer.Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
            else
                Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
        } 
        //if (HitBlock() && hit.transform.tag == "damage"){
        //  hit.damage.damage(1);
        //}

    }
    function getCam(){
        var ts : Transform[] = transform.GetComponentsInChildren.<Transform>();
        for (var t : Transform in ts)
            if (t.gameObject.name == "Main Camera")
                return t.gameObject;
    }
    function HitBlock() : boolean { 
        return Physics.Raycast(getCam().transform.position, getCam().transform.forward, hit, range, blockLayer); 
    }
    function getCopn(){
        for(i in FindObjectsOfType(typeof(computer))){
            if(i.open)
                return true;
            Debug.Log(i);
            Debug.Log(i.open);
        }
        return false;
    }
    function saveWorld(){
        var allblocks : blockld[];
        allblocks = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(blockld));
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("objects",allblocks.length);
        var temp : GameObject;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("saved",1);
        GUI.Box(Rect(200,200,280,300),"saving, give me a sec...");
        //SceneView.RepaintAll();
        for(var i : int=0;i<allblocks.length;i++){
            temp=allblocks[i].gameObject;
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_x",temp.transform.position.x);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_y",temp.transform.position.y);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_z",temp.transform.position.z);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_rx",temp.transform.rotation.x);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_ry",temp.transform.rotation.y);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_rz",temp.transform.rotation.z);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_rw",temp.transform.rotation.w);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(i.ToString()+"_ID", allblocks[i].id);
            if(temp.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>()){
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_vx",temp.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.x);
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_vy",temp.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.y);
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_vz",temp.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.z);
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_ax",temp.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity.x);
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_ay",temp.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity.y);
                PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(i.ToString()+"_az",temp.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity.z);
            }
        }
        var planet = GameObject.Find("planet0");
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PX",player.transform.position.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PY",player.transform.position.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PZ",player.transform.position.z);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("VX",player.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("VY",player.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("VZ",player.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.z);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_x",planet.transform.position.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_y",planet.transform.position.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_z",planet.transform.position.z);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_vx",planet.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_vy",planet.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_vz",planet.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.z);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_rx",player.transform.rotation.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_ry",player.transform.rotation.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_rz",player.transform.rotation.z);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_rw",player.transform.rotation.w);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_ax",player.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_ay",player.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p0_az",player.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity.z);
        planet = GameObject.Find("planet1");
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_x",planet.transform.position.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_y",planet.transform.position.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_z",planet.transform.position.z);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_vx",planet.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_vy",planet.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_vz",planet.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().velocity.z);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_rx",player.transform.rotation.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_ry",player.transform.rotation.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_rz",player.transform.rotation.z);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_rw",player.transform.rotation.w);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_ax",player.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_ay",player.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("p1_az",player.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity.z);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

In CmdSyncBlock i get this error when code is running:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

What I have done:

- Added networkTransforms and NetworkIdentities
- Registered spawnable prefrabs

How can I properly make these objects show up on all clients without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have network identity script on your block prefab(s) and then register them as spawnable prefabs in your NetworkManager.

If you don't want to use the unity's default NetworkManager then you can also register the prefabs yourself on the code.

See link for more info: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSpawning.html

Also, you cannot syncvar gameobjects. Instead you should syncvar the ID and inside your CmdBuild, define which block you want to use based on the synched id.

Comment: Also do note, you cannot syncvar gameobjects, only basic variables (or list of variables)

Comment: I did do this, however keep your answer for future users. it is a very important point.  It appears that the variable "block" was not syncing. mention it and i'll give you a check mark!